# JSON data do not load in UICollectionView Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

currently I'm trying to load data from News API, before this I had tried to implement it with UITableView and it works but it not works in UICollectionView. I'm using URLSession for networking operations.

PS; *I did this with premade collectionView from object library in Storyborad*

**What I Expect to happen**

- JSON data load into CollectionView

**What actually happens**

- JSON does not load in CollectionView and the screen is empty

**What I have tried to solve my problems**

- Reload collectionView after the JSON appends

***NewsCollectionVC.swift***

```
class NewsCollectionVC: UIViewController {

    var newsResult = [NewsModel]()
    var newsManager = NewsManager()
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        newsManager.fetchNews()
        newsManager.delegate = self
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
}

extension NewsCollectionVC : NewsManagerDelegate {
    func didSendNewsData(_ newsManager: NewsManager, with news: [NewsModel]) {
        
        self.newsResult.append(contentsOf: news)
        DispatchQueue.main.async{

            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            print(self.newsResult.count)
        }
    }
}

extension NewsCollectionVC : UICollectionViewDataSource{
    

    // Tell delegate how many cv need to show
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        

        return newsResult.count
    }
    
    // Tell delegate content of cv
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let listOfNews = newsResult[indexPath.row]
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CViewCell
        cell.author.text = listOfNews.author
        //cell.author.text = "listOfNews.author"
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

***NewsManager.swift***

```
protocol NewsManagerDelegate {
    func didSendNewsData (_ newsManager: NewsManager, with news : [NewsModel])
}


struct NewsManager{
    
    var delegate : NewsManagerDelegate?
    
    let newsUrl = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=apple"
    let key = "MY_API_KEY"
    
    func fetchNews(){
        let urlString = "\(newsUrl)&apiKey=\(key)"
        performRequest(with : urlString)
    }
    
    func fetchNews(page : Int){
        let urlString = "\(newsUrl)&page=\(page)&apiKey=\(key)"
        performRequest(with: urlString)
    }

    
    func performRequest(with urlString : String){
        
        
        // 1. create URL object
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {fatalError("There's problem to fetch data from this url")}
        
        // 2. create session, object to do networking
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        //3. give session a task
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if error != nil{
                print("Error in giving session a task \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                
            } else{
                // determine if data is exist
                if let safeData = data {
                    //convert data to string
                    //let dataString = String(data: safeData, encoding: .utf8)
                    //print(dataString)
                    
                    // Parse the data here
                    guard let news = parseJSON(safeData) else{ fatalError("Error parsing data from JSON")}
                   
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        delegate?.didSendNewsData(self, with: news)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        //start the task
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func parseJSON(_ newsData : Data) -> [NewsModel]?{
        
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
        var newsModel = [NewsModel]()
        
        do{
            
            let decodeData = try decoder.decode(NewsData.self, from: newsData)
            print(decodeData.articles[0].title)
            print(decodeData.articles[0].source.name)
            print(decodeData.articles[0].urlToImage)
            
            
          
            
            for article in decodeData.articles {
                
                let author = article.author
                let title = article.title
                let decription = article.description
                let url = article.url
                let urlToImage = article.urlToImage
                let publishedAt = article.publishedAt
                let sourcesName = article.source.name
                
                
                    guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: urlToImage) else{fatalError("Error to get image data from URL")}
                     guard let imageContent = UIImage(data: imageData) else {fatalError("Error load image from image data")}
                    let data = NewsModel(author: author, title: title, decription: decription, url: url, image: imageContent, publishedAt: publishedAt, sourcesName: sourcesName)
                    
                        newsModel.append(data)

            }
            
            return newsModel
            
        } catch{
            print("Error decode the data : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    
        }

        return newsModel
    }
}
```

***NewsModel.swift***

```
struct NewsModel {
    let author : String
    let title : String
    let decription : String
    let url : String
    let image : UIImage
    let publishedAt : String
    let sourcesName : String
    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running your code after adding breakpoints to see what part of it is failing?

Comment: @Abizern ya I already at a breakpoint, it seems at numberOfItemsInSection is 0, I not sure why, when I try it at tableview it returns 20

Comment: @EricAya as you can see there, I decode the JSON and parse it back to the data model, it is possible to have multiple URLSession in a single class , I plan to use that kind of method that you suggest but I can't find how to do that one.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in your delegate method to see _when_ it is being run?

Comment: @Abizern I just try to add the breakpoint at the newsManagerDelegate and class that adopt it, it all returns success and not nil

Comment: Could you clarify which method is called and which isn't? Is `print(self.newsResult.count)` printed into console? Is `delegate?.didSendNewsData(self, with: news)` called? Etc. What's the frame of `collectionView`?

Comment: @Larme the print statement does not run, yup the delegate method is called when any class adopt it, frame of collection view is in the center of the VC

Comment: That's strange, if the statement doesn't run BUT the method is called? Could you add a print in `didSendNewsData(_ newsManager: NewsManager, with news: [NewsModel])`to be sure that the method is called? Add print at the beginning of each methods, and find out which one aren't called (or use Breakpoints).

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your time in answering these questions, the answer is because I assign the instance for the delegate after calling the instance methods.

It should be ✅

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        newsManager.delegate = self
        newsManager.fetchNews()
        
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

rather than ❎

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        newsManager.fetchNews()
        newsManager.delegate = self
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```